# Exception in GRPC when trying to execute FIrebase admin

Tags: grpc

I wanted to authenticate in my program after building it.

After building the program using nutka, I get an gRPC error when authenticating my account.
Exception ignored in: 'grpc._cython.cygrpc.ssl_roots_override_callback'
E0614 11:25:09.201000000 6068 src/core/lib/security/security_connector/ssl_units.cc:576] ASSERTION FAILED: pem_root_certs != nullptr

How can I fix the error? Switching to another database is not an option for me